# modifying variables in an override method resets them to false

Tags: c#, mono, unity-game-engine, overriding, abstract

I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class HitableAbstract : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float TimeLeft;

    public abstract bool OnHit();
}
```

and a child class who inherits from this class:

```
public class Target : HitableAbstract
{
    bool isHit = false;

    public override bool OnHit ()
    {
        if (!isHit)
        {
            isHit = true;
            return (true);
        }

        return (false);
    }
}
```

However, after calling the onHit, isHit stays false. Is this some kind of behaviour of abstract classes that i should know of?

On the internet, i can only find 'get's in override methods. no assignments..

Comment: "However, after calling the onHit, isHit stays false." How do you check that it's `false`?

Comment: by the unity inspector, which shows variables in realtime! also tried Debug printing the variable in a method, it is still false. I checked if the onHit method is exectuted by a Debug print, it is! When i debug print the variable inside onHit, it returns true..

Comment: I just tried and isHit is showing true. `Target t = new Target(); t.printIsHit(); t.OnHit(); t.printIsHit();`  and in Target `public void printIsHit() { Console.WriteLine(isHit); }`

Answer (score 1):

You are probably hitting one variable and checking the status of another one with Unity inspector.

The code you posted is right and there is no 'hidden' behavior of abstract classes.